# Printing first combination among various combinations

Tags: python-3.x, loops

So I have a question:

**Given an even number (greater than 2), return two prime numbers whose sum will be equal to given number. There are several combinations possible. Print only first such pair**

This is for additional reference:

*Input: The first line contains T, the number of test cases. The following T lines consist of a number each, for which we'll find two prime numbers.

Note: The number would always be an even number.

Output: For every test case print two prime numbers space separated, such that the smaller number appears first. Answer for each test case must be in a new line.

Constraints: 1 ≤ T ≤ 70

2 < N ≤ 10000

Example:

Input:

5, 74, 1024, 66, 8, 9990

Output: 3 71, 3 1021, 5 61, 3 5, 17 9973

Here is what I tried:

```
import math
def prime(n):

    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True       

T = int(input("No of inputs: ")) #T is the no of test cases

input_num = []
for i in range(0,T):
    input_num.append(input())

lst2= []
if T in range(1,71):
    for i in input_num:
        if (i in range(3,1000)) and (i % 2 == 0):
            for j in range(0,i):
                if prime(j) == True:
                    lst2.append(j)
                for x in lst2:
                    for y in lst2:
                        if x + y == j:
                            print(x,end = ' ')
                            print(y)
```

This is only taking inputs but not returning outputs.

Also my code is currently intended for all the combinations but  what I want is only the first pair and I am not able to do that

Answer (score 0):

I found a more elegant solution to this problem [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-two-prime-numbers-with-given-sum/). Java, C, C++ etc versions of solution is also present there. I am going to give the python3 solution.

```py
# Python 3 program to find a prime number 
# pair whose sum is equal to given number 
# Python 3 program to print super primes 
# less than or equal to n. 

# Generate all prime numbers less than n. 
def SieveOfEratosthenes(n, isPrime): 

    # Initialize all entries of boolean 
    # array as True. A value in isPrime[i] 
    # will finally be False if i is Not a 
    # prime, else True bool isPrime[n+1] 
    isPrime[0] = isPrime[1] = False
    for i in range(2, n+1): 
        isPrime[i] = True

    p = 2
    while(p*p <= n): 
        # If isPrime[p] is not changed, 
        # then it is a prime 
        if (isPrime[p] == True): 
            # Update all multiples of p 
            i = p*p 
            while(i <= n): 
                isPrime[i] = False
                i += p 
        p += 1

# Prints a prime pair with given sum 
def findPrimePair(n):
    # Generating primes using Sieve 
    isPrime = [0] * (n+1) 
    SieveOfEratosthenes(n, isPrime) 

    # Traversing all numbers to find  
    # first pair 
    for i in range(0, n): 
        if (isPrime[i] and isPrime[n - i]): 
            print(i,(n - i)) 
            return

# Driven program 
n = 74
findPrimePair(n)
```

Comment: This is really appreciated and I will try this solution but I want to correct my code.Although its really basic,I want to know how I can work upon my logic to improve my code

Comment: If this is the case, then surely, I am going to get through your code right now. Lets fix what needs fixing.